# FileZilla uploads file multiple times and only one of them is actually with the correct content

Tags: filezilla

I am using FileZilla to upload a file through SFTP and it randomly uploads it multiple times.

For e.g. sometimes it might upload two files with zero bytes and one file with correct content and then sometimes one file with zero bytes and one file with correct content.

Basically by the time i see the message that File transfer was successful in the logs it attempts the same upload multiple times. And in the logs it does not show the upload attempts multiple times.

I tried using another client for the SFTP upload and it works fine.

Any suggestions why this might be happening.

Comment: *And in the logs it does not show the upload attempts multiple times.* So how do you know that it uploads the file multiple times? Show us the log file (a real log file, not the message log from GUI) and corresponding server log, if possible.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I am talking about the real log file, not the comments from the GUI. And I can see three files in my destination folder that's how i know it uploads multiple times but only one of them is valid. I will upload the real log file later on but honestly I doubt if it would help you much.

Comment: So it uploads the same file three times under a different names?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Same file same name, the OS's mechanism to add a file with same name takes over and adds a file with (1) appended to it.

Comment: OK, show us the log please. What other SFTP client did you try?